# Mi instancia de Amazon no puede subir imágenes a Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, aws

No puedo subir imágenes desde el panel de administración de Wordpress. Me da el siguiente error.

```
 ARCHIVO.png El archivo subido no se ha podido mover a wp-content/uploads/2017/06.
```

Los permisos de mi directorio /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads es

```
drwxr-sr-x 3 ec2-user apache 4096 jul 20 01:14 uploads
```

¿Qué necesito hacer en la instancia para que me deje subir archivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu carpeta tiene permisos de escritura para el usuario ec2-user, pero el grupo apache es el que está tratando de escribir los archivos, bastaría con darle los permisos correspondientes:

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```